# Error inflating fragment after upgrading Android Studio to Arctic Fox

Tags: android, android-studio

I saw that Jetpack Compose was out from beta so I figured I'd upgrade to Arctic Fox.  Compose looks really efficient and I wanted to add it to my current project.

However, after upgrading my project I've had nothing but build errors and crashes.  From what I can tell its having a problem inflating the layout which is then causing a `lateinit property not initialized error`.  It seems it's not recognizing the `<include>` tag in my layout files for some reason, or maybe its the `<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>` tags.

Somewhere I read to update the AGP and Gradle versions to 7, but that didn't change anything.  Other projects run without upgrading, but sometimes blowup after upgrading also.  In the other projects that blow up with the same error, it always looks like its at the end of a Toolbar tag.  I didn't make any changes to my code only the plugin versions, so I don't know why it would have problems with something that used to be working just fine.

I'm completely lost. I've been fighting the SDK for a week and gotten no where.

My only options seem to be revert to the old SDK or try Bumblebee Canary 7.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_layout"
        layout="@layout/nav_host"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"/> // line 24 in activity_main.xml

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**nav_host.xml**

```
<LinearLayout>

<include
    layout="@layout/view_main_app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<include
    layout="@layout/view_search_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation" /> // line 37 in nav_host.xml
</FrameLayout>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setTheme(R.style.Theme_MyApp_NoActionBar)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)  // debug show it starts blowing up here
```

**Error Message**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myapp.android, PID: 7891
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp.android/com.myapp.android.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24 in com.myapp.android:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #37 in com.myapp.android:layout/nav_host: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24 in com.myapp.android:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #37 in com.myapp.android:layout/nav_host: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #37 in com.myapp.android:layout/nav_host: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property searchBar has not been initialized
        at com.myapp.android.MainActivity.toggleSearchBar(MainActivity.kt:193)
        at com.myapp.android.ui.tabs.FragmentListContainer.onCreateView(FragmentListContainer.kt:52)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1647)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3128)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:3065)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2988)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.ensureInflatedView(FragmentStateManager.java:392)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:281)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:140)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:319)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:298)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1069)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:997)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1126)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1263)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1119)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
        at com.myapp.android.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:51)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: Do you get a warning on the `<fragment>` tag? You should never be using that and only be using `FragmentContainerView`.

Comment: Changing to `FragmentContainerView` fixed it, but I started this project with the default Navigation Drawer Activity which auto generated the `<fragment>` in the content_main.xml(I think I refactored it to nav_host.xml).  Even in Arctic Fox The default Navigation Drawer Activity uses `<fragment>` complete with a warning to change it.